# Spring boot resourse handler does not resolve static files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using the Spring boot 1.5.2 with war packaging.

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

Here is my resource handler configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ServletContextInitializer, EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {


    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebConfigurer.class);

    private final Environment env;

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    public WebConfigurer(Environment env, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {

        this.env = env;
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }


        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/public/**"))
                registry.addResourceHandler("/public/images/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/images/");
        }
          @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        if (env.getActiveProfiles().length != 0) {
            log.info("Web application configuration, using profiles: {}", (Object[]) env.getActiveProfiles());
        }
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ASYNC);
        initMetrics(servletContext, disps);
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
            initCachingHttpHeadersFilter(servletContext, disps);
        }
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)) {
            initH2Console(servletContext);
        }
        log.info("Web application fully configured");
    }

    /**
     * Customize the Servlet engine: Mime types, the document root, the cache.
     */
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        // IE issue, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/711
        mappings.add("html", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        // CloudFoundry issue, see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/64
        mappings.add("json", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
        // When running in an IDE or with ./mvnw spring-boot:run, set location of the static web assets.
        setLocationForStaticAssets(container);

        /*
         * Enable HTTP/2 for Undertow - https://twitter.com/ankinson/status/829256167700492288
         * HTTP/2 requires HTTPS, so HTTP requests will fallback to HTTP/1.1.
         * See the JHipsterProperties class and your application-*.yml configuration files
         * for more information.
         */
        if (jHipsterProperties.getHttp().getVersion().equals(JHipsterProperties.Http.Version.V_2_0) &&
            container instanceof UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {

            ((UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                .addBuilderCustomizers(builder ->
                    builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true));
        }
    }

    private void setLocationForStaticAssets(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        File root;
        String prefixPath = resolvePathPrefix();
        root = new File(prefixPath + "target/www/");
        if (root.exists() && root.isDirectory()) {
            container.setDocumentRoot(root);
        }
    }
```

I write my images urls as follows http://localhost:8080/public/images/products/wideprint.jpg, but get 404 response.

[Edit] I am really tired from looking for a solution for this really simple problem, my temporary solution is just to create the controller that handles images. P.S I do not recoment this solution in any way.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/image/{directory}", produces = "image/*")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImageBody(@PathVariable("directory") String directory,
                                               @RequestParam("imageName") String imageName) throws IOException {
        File image = new File(this.imageStoragePath+ "\\" + directory + "\\" + imageName);
        if (image.exists() && image.canRead()) {
             return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(image), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: Would it work if you comment out `setLocationForStaticAssets()` method invocation?

Comment: did you try putting your image in `src/main/resources/static/public/images/products/wideprint.jpg`? spring boot serves static resources out of `src/main/resources/static` by default.

Comment: @Slava Semushin Yes, does not work.

Comment: @ninj yes i think i tried all default locations